# print no of items fetched using pagination in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I want to display count of no of items fetched per page using pagination like

```
Displaying 10 items
```

Although limit is set to pagination to 20 but It will not always fetch 20 items when there are only 15 items or 10 items or 25 items.
In these cases it will either have one page result for items count 15 and 10 or two pages result for items count 25.

I want to print the no of items showing on each page. Like for total items 25.

It will show `Displaying 20 items` on first page and `Displaying 5 items` on second page.

How is it possible in CakePHP 3.2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I get it working in CakePHP 3.2

There are two ways you can do it.

> 1. Using `Helpers`

create a file `paginator-counter.php` in `/config` directory with your tokens and string and add a line in `/src/view/AppView.php`

```
public function initialize()
{
  $this->loadHelper('Paginator', ['templates' => 'paginator-counter']);
}
```

This will load the file located at **config/paginator-templates.php**

And then use it in your view.

For more : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html

> 2. Using direct string

Just print in view where you want to print the `counter`

```
<?= $this->Paginator->counter('Showing {{current}} results out of {{count}}') ?>
```

More tokens can be found Here : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#creating-a-page-counter

**I'm using 2nd way to print counter *ie.,* using sting directly**

Comment: we can only provide  some assistance .It is good, U discover it in a good way

Comment: Thank you again. Your assistance helped me to figure this out.